# Check if button was clicked and return a alert outside the click function

Tags: jquery, click

I want to see if a button was clicked. If it was clicked, return a alert outside of the click function. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = 0;
  $('body').on('click', '#publish', function() {
    test = 1;
  });

  if(test == 1) {
    alert('jay!');
  }
});
```

Not it doesn't show the alert window upon click. Why? Do I have to use the if statement inside the click function? I want this code to work as it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/TXERr/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "click function" is the event handler that gets executed upon a click. The "on" function only registers this event handler and the following code is executed afterwards (prior to any click). Everything that is supposed to happen when the button gets clicked needs to be inside the event handler ("click function") or needs to be called from there.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/TXERr/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code can't work because the `if` statement is executed before the click event. (and as sidenote: as a good practice always use triple equality in your comparison)

Do instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = 0;

  function checkTest() {
    if(test === 1) {
       alert('jay!');
    }
  }

  $('body').on('click', '#publish', function() {
    test = 1;
    checkTest();
  });


});
```